# Linux - boot in runlevel3 and add X11 components

Tags: linux, user-interface, embedded, x11, runlevel

I want to build a minimum Linux for embedded devices that comes with Firefox only.

Questions:

1. Is it ever possible to add X11 components to runlevel3 and
   upgrade it to runlevel5?
2. Is it possible to setup a Linux in runlevel3 with minimum display support so that I be able to  run
   Firefox? (Not interested in text based browsers)

I gave it a go but I got lots of dependency errors trying to install *X11-common* with *apt-get* in runlevel3.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Sure, in the good old days where a gui could imply system load you didn't always want this was common, and then you'd execute `startx` or similar.  Of course now it's more complex in that you're typically not just running an x server and window manager, but all sorts of other desk accessories.  Note also that X does not mean the program necessarily runs on the same box as the display, ie, if you are using an external machine for display then you wouldn't really run X (as in the server and accessories) on the embedded system, but only run X client apps that connect to an external server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) is a step-by-step instruction book for anyone who wants to gain a good understanding of how to build own custom Linux distro.

1. There is a dedicated topic about [X Window System Environment](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/installing.html)

This includes the base LFS project and a bunch of extensions derived from it. For embedded systems [Cross Linux From Scratch](http://clfs.org/) is of particular interest.

Another option - in case you want to do it faster but losing deep understanding - is using some Embedded Linux distro builder like [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/)